# Check if a string is null or empty in XSLT

Tags: xslt, null, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I check if a value is null or empty with [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL)?

For example, if `categoryName` is empty? I'm using a *when choosing* construct.

For example:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="categoryName !=null">
        <xsl:value-of select="categoryName " />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="other" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Can you expand the code example?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you probably don't want to use `xsl:when` for node-tests. Consider `<xsl:template match="Category[categoryName[not(node())]]">...` together with a `<xsl:template match="Category">...`. The processor will then make the correct decisions for you and you do not need to write out the business logic in nested `xsl:choose` anymore. In many cases, using matching templates makes writing stylesheets easier.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

```
test="categoryName != ''"
```

**Edit**: This covers the most likely interpretation, in my opinion, of "[not] null or empty" as inferred from the question, including it's pseudo-code and my own early experience with XSLT. I.e., "What is the equivalent of the following Java?":

```
// Equivalent Java, NOT XSLT
!(categoryName == null || categoryName.equals(""))
```

For more details e.g., distinctly identifying null vs. empty, see [johnvey's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/825924/93345) and/or [the XSLT 'fiddle'](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTAf/3) I've adapted from that answer, which includes the option in Michael Kay's comment as well as the sixth possible interpretation.

Comment: The detailed semantics of this test is: return true if there is at least one categoryName element whose string value is an empty string.

Comment: @jelovirt did you mean to say if there is at least one categoryName that's NOT an empty string? (I'm an xsl newbie, so forgive any potential stupidity to my question.)

Comment: This answer, while accepted and highly voted, is also very misleading. It really depends what you mean by "null or empty". If you want a test that succeeds if categoryName is either absent, or present with a zero-length value, you should use `test="not(categoryName = '')"`. The supplied answer will return false if the categoryName element is absent, which in my interpretation of the question makes it a wrong answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I've updated the answer to provide more details. Thanks for the comment and for the Saxon XSLT processor!

Comment: How can I translate `<xsl:for-each select="root/*[matches(name(.), 'grp')]">` so it can be used in VS2010?

Comment: @SiKni8: Please start another question with some more details e.g., what you mean by using the snippet in VS2010 (e.g., execution? IntelliSense? Breakpoints?) as well as XML/XSLT sample fragments. I sent you some contact information via the link in your profile so you can notify me when it's posted. Short version of my answer: use an XSLT 2.0 engine or recurse with string-length() and substring().

Comment: @steamer... When I use the line it keep saying match() is unknown xsl function. I will surely open a new question and let you know. Thank tou.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, I like to explicitly check with boolean type where possible for readability, such as: `not(string-length(string(categoryName)) > 0)`

Comment: @steamer25 The XSLT 'fiddle' link goes to a page with error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

Comment: Thank you @steamer25. Please note that in your answer, for XSLT the double double quota `""` must be double single quota `''`, as it is done in the fiddle.

Answer (score 301):

Absent of any other information, I'll assume the following XML:

```
<group>
    <item>
        <id>item 1</id>
        <CategoryName>blue</CategoryName>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>item 2</id>
        <CategoryName></CategoryName>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>item 3</id>
    </item>
    ...
</group>
```

A sample use case would look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/group/item">
    <xsl:if test="CategoryName">
        <!-- will be instantiated for item #1 and item #2 -->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(CategoryName)">
        <!-- will be instantiated for item #3 -->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="CategoryName != ''">
        <!-- will be instantiated for item #1 -->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="CategoryName = ''">
        <!-- will be instantiated for item #2 -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How do you test for instances of `</CategoryName>` ? , empty string tests don't work for this

Comment: It's appreciated that you included multiple examples to show how each expression results.

Comment: @raffian: in XSLT, or related technologies (XQuery, DOM, XDM, Schema etc), end-tags are not considered as separate entities. Instead, you only deal with nodes, or elements in this case, which is the whole between start-tag and end-tag. In short, there is no way to test for `</CategoryName>`, nor is there any need for.

Comment: I starred the question specifically for this answer, and while the question is pretty old, this one seems much more deserving of being the selected answer

Comment: What about exists()? I can't find much documentation about how it works. Any idea where it falls in this list?

Comment: Lol, well I CAN just check it myself, but that would require... effort. Here's what I found: 'test="exists(CategoryName)"' will be instantiated for Item #1 and Item #2, meaning that it behaves just like 'test="CategoryName"'
I don't know if "exists()" is generally available or is implementation-specific, but it might be a more explicit/readable way to say 'test="CategoryName"'

Comment: Furthermore, 'test="not(CategoryName != '')' is the only test that will evaluate to "true" for both item #2 and item #3

Answer (score 78):

From *[Empty Element](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N3328.html#d4887e64)*:

To test if the value of a certain node is empty

It depends on what you mean by empty.

- Contains no child nodes: `not(node())`
- Contains no text content: `not(string(.))`
- Contains no text other than whitespace: `not(normalize-space(.))`
- Contains nothing except comments: `not(node()[not(self::comment())])`

Comment: +1. Some notes. The first bulletpoint also tests for text-content, which is also a node. The second bulletpoint tests for any text node at any depth, if you want to know if the current node does not contain text, but can contain other nodes, you can use `not(text())`. An alternative to your 2nd bullet is also `not(.//text())`. As your last bullet shows: there are many ways to consider "nothingness" ;).

Comment: Very practical: To test if a string is *not* empty, you can just test the string itself! `if ($mystring) then ... else ...`

Answer (score 26):

What about?

```
test="not(normalize-space(categoryName)='')"
```

Comment: This works great. Even when there is a comment inside `<categoryName>   <!-- some comment -->  </categoryName>` and otherwise no meaningful text, this still evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 10):

First two deal with null value and second two deal with empty string.

```
<xsl:if test="USER/FIRSTNAME">
    USERNAME is not null
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(USER/FIRSTNAME)">
    USERNAME is null
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="USER/FIRSTNAME=''">
     USERNAME is empty string
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="USER/FIRSTNAME!=''">
     USERNAME is not empty string
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Scary. What if there are multiple users or multiple firstnames? Use `xsl:apply-templates` and matching templates to get what you want, much easier.

Answer (score 8):

> How can I check if a value is null or empty with XSL?
>
> For example, if `categoryName` is empty?

**This is probably the simplest XPath expression** (the one in accepted answer provides a test for the opposite, and would be longer, if negated):

```
not(string(categoryName))
```

**Explanation**:

The argument to the `not()` function above is `false()` exactly when there is no `categoryName` child ("null") of the context item, or the (single such) `categoryName` child has string value -- the empty string.

> I'm using a *when choosing* construct.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <xsl:choose>
>     <xsl:when test="categoryName !=null">
>         <xsl:value-of select="categoryName " />
>     </xsl:when>
>     <xsl:otherwise>
>         <xsl:value-of select="other" />
>     </xsl:otherwise>
> </xsl:choose>
> ```

**In XSLT 2.0 use**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="concat(categoryName,  $vOther[not(string(current()/categoryName))])"/>
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOther" select="'Other'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="concat(categoryName,$vOther[not(string(current()/categoryName))])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<categoryName>X</categoryName>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
X
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<categoryName></categoryName>
```

or on this:

```
<categoryName/>
```

or on this

```
<somethingElse>Y</somethingElse>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
Other
```

---

Similarly, use this **XSLT 1.0** transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOther" select="'Other'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "concat(categoryName,  substring($vOther, 1 div not(string(categoryName))))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: No conditionals are used at all. Learn more about the importance of avoiding conditional constructs in this nice Pluralsight course:

["**Tactical Design Patterns in .NET: Control Flow**"](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/tactical-design-patterns-dot-net-control-flow/table-of-contents)

Comment: Hi Dimitre, i need your solution for 1.0, so do I need to code it in every tags that I have or is there a simpler way to impement it for the whole XML?

Comment: @zyberjock, It is unclear what you are asking. Please, post a question and send me a comment with a link. Follow the guidelines how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hi @Dimitre, I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150093/set-a-default-value-for-each-empty-xml-tags-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, you might want to know when the value is specifically null, which is particularly necessary when using XML which has been serialized from .NET objects.  While the accepted answer works for this, it also returns the same result when the string is blank or empty, i.e. '', so you can't differentiate.

```
<group>
    <item>
        <id>item 1</id>
        <CategoryName xsi:nil="true" />
    </item>
</group>
```

So you can simply test the attribute.

```
<xsl:if test="CategoryName/@xsi:nil='true'">
   Hello World.
</xsl:if>
```

Sometimes it's necessary to know the exact state and you can't simply check if CategoryName is instantiated, because unlike say Javascript

```
<xsl:if test="CategoryName">
   Hello World.
</xsl:if>
```

Will return true for a null element.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old, but between all the answers, I miss one that is a common approach for this use-case in XSLT development.

I am imagining that the missing code from the OP looks something like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="categoryName !=null">
            <xsl:value-of select="categoryName " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="other" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</category>
```

And that the input looks something like this:

```
<categories>
    <category>
       <categoryName>Books</categoryName>
    </category>
    <category>
       <categoryName>Magazines</categoryName>
       <categoryName>Periodicals</categoryName>
       <categoryName>Journals</categoryName>
    </category>
    <category>
        <categoryName><!-- please fill in category --></categoryName>
    </category>
    <category>
        <categoryName />
    </category>
    <category />
</categories>
```

I.e., I assume there can be zero, empty, single or multiple `categoryName` elements. To deal with all these cases using `xsl:choose`-style constructs, or in other words, imperatively, is quickly getting messy (even more so if elements can be at different levels!). A typical programming idiom in XSLT is using templates (hence the T in XSLT), which is declarative programming, not imperative (you don't tell the processor what to do, you just tell what you want output if certain conditions are met). For this use-case, that can look something like the following:

```
<!-- positive test, any category with a valid categoryName -->
<xsl:template match="category[categoryName[text()]]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<!-- any other category (without categoryName, "null", with comments etc) -->
<xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:text>Category: Other</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- matching the categoryName itself for easy handling of multiple names -->
<xsl:template match="categoryName">
    <xsl:text>Category: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

This works (with any XSLT version), because the first one above has a higher precedence (it has a predicate). The "fall-through" matching template, the second one, catches anything that is not valid. The third one then takes care of outputting the `categoryName` value in a proper way.

Note that in this scenario there is no need to specifially match `categories` or `category`, because the processor will automatically process all children, unless we tell it otherwise (in this example, the second and third template do not further process the children, because there is no `xsl:apply-templates` in them).

This approach is more easily extendible then the imperative approach, because it automically deals with multiple categories and it can be expanded for other elements or exceptions by just adding another matching template. **Programming without if-branches**.

Note: there is no such thing as `null` in XML. There is [xsi:nil](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil), but that is rarely used, especially rarely in untyped scenarios without a schema of some sort.

Comment: Congrats on mentioning "*Programming without if-branches*".  There are some people who fail to understand the importance of this. For all of them here is a link to a very nice Pluralsight course on this topic: "*Tactical Design Patterns in .NET: Control Flow*" by Zoran Horvat: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/tactical-design-patterns-dot-net-control-flow/table-of-contents   A must-read!

Answer (score 5):

If there is a possibility that the element does not exist in the XML I would test both that the element is present and that the string-length is greater than zero:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="categoryName and string-length(categoryName) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="categoryName " />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="other" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: The string value of an empty node set (which is what the XPath expression `categoryName` gives you when there are no `categoryName` child elements in the current context) is defined to be the empty string, so this is redundant - `string-length(categoryName)` is zero if there are no `categoryName` elements.

Answer (score 3):

If a node has no value available in the input xml like below xpath,

```
<node>
    <ErrorCode/>
</node>
```

string() function converts into empty value. So this works fine:

```
string(/Node/ErrorCode) =''
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for me:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string(number(categoryName)) = 'NaN'"> - </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
    <xsl:number value="categoryName" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Or the other way around:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string(number(categoryName)) != 'NaN'">
    <xsl:number value="categoryName" />
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> - </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Note: If you don't check null values or handle null values, IE7 returns -2147483648 instead of NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it better just testing for string length since many times the field is not null, just empty

> <xsl:when test="string-length(field-you-want-to-test)<1">

Answer (score 0):

By my experience the best way is:

```
<xsl:when test="not(string(categoryName))">
    <xsl:value-of select="other" />
</xsl:when>
<otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="categoryName" />
</otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple categoryName/text() Such test works fine on `<categoryName/>` and also `<categoryName></categoryName>`.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="categoryName/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="categoryName" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="other" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```