# XSLT: "test" results confusion

Tags: xslt, testing

I'm finding that while this test returns true:

`test="string-length(foo) = 0"`

However, for some reason, both of these tests are returning false:

`test="foo = ''"`

test="foo = null"

Any idea what might be going on?  Is there some other state that foo could be in that would result in a 0 length, while still not being equal to '' or null?

Additionally - if I output:

`X<xsl:value-of select="foo" />X`

outputs: XX

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt

Comment: Thank you - I found that exact same article moments ago.  Specifically, my misunderstanding was assuming that not(foo) and foo = null would return the same results and apparently that's not correct.  If the element is absent, it is not equal to null. Instead, testing for a missing element must be tested for with not(foo).  Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is not _null_ in XSLT, read Martin Honnen's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If foo is an empty node-set then `string(foo)` is "", and `string-length(foo)` is zero, but `foo = ''` is false. XPath is full of surprises.

The explanation is that `foo = ""` doesn't mean `string(foo) = ""` as you might expect, but rather `some $F in foo satisfies $F = ""` (which you can write in full in XPath 2.0). And if foo is an empty set then the existential test is clearly false.

Comment: Very concise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you do `test="foo = null"` you compare the `foo` child element(s) of the context node to the `null` child element(s) of the context node.