# Using XSL Choose to Substitute Empty String

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to substitute an empty value in a csv file with a number.

Here's an example:

1111111,,11222

So I tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="//tr" />

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
  <document>
     <content name="title">
         <xsl:value-of select="td[1]/text()" />
      </content>
     <content name="loanID">
        <xsl:value-of select="td[1]/text()" />
     </content>
     <content name="cNumber">
        <xsl:variable name="score" select="td[2]/text()" />
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$score=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="550" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="td[18]/text()" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </content>
  </document>
 </xsl:template>
```

I constantly get a null value for the cNumber node when the value is empty in the row, and I'm expecting my code to substitute the empty value for '550'.  What am I doing wrong?  I checked this question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt)  and it seems like this should work.  I'm using a special application for this but my guess is the fault lies with me.

Thanks

Comment: What's the input? Also looks like the output of your stylesheet is not producing a CSV file.

Comment: `$score` contains the value of `td[2]` when it is empty you show `550`, when it is not empty you use the value of `td[18]`, but what if `td[18]` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the td element is empty, then `td/text()` returns an empty sequence/node-set, and when you compare an empty sequence to '', the result is false. This is one of the reasons that many people advise against using `text()`. You're not interested here in the text node, you are interested in the string value of the td element, and to get that you should use

```
<xsl:variable name="score" select="string(td[2])" />
```

Your other uses of text() are also incorrect, though you're only likely to see a problem if your XML input contains comments or processing instructions. But you should get out of this coding habit, and replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="td[1]/text()" />
```

by

```
<xsl:value-of select="td[1]" />
```

As a general rule, when you see `/text()` in an XPath expression it's usually wrong.