# Set a Default value for each empty XML tags in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to write a default text or number to an empty XML tag using XSLT 1.0, then upon searching here in StackOverflow I happen to look at the solution of Dimitre in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt/34552872?noredirect=1#comment63725123_34552872)

What I need is for example I have a tag like below:

```
<Number></Number> <!--Which is empty-->
```

or

```
<Text></Text> <!--Which is also empty-->
```

What I need is to put a Default value for each empty tags in my XML like `<Number>0.00</Number>` for numeric tags and `<Text>nil</Text>` for Alphanumeric tags, I have quite a big XML so is there any way to make it like an identity template where it will always be read from my input then transform it to Insert the default on empty strings or I can only do the code like below on each field/tags?

```
<xsl:copy-of select="concat(categoryName,$vOther[not(string(current()/categoryName))])"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Number[not(node())]">
    <Number>0.00</Number>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Text[not(node())]">
    <Text>nill</Text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (as none was provided):

```
<t>
  <Number>10</Number>
  <Number/>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
  <Text/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <Number>10</Number>
   <Number>0.00</Number>
   <Text>Hello</Text>
   <Text>nill</Text>
</t>
```

**Note**:

In order to get the systematic knowledge to solve basic problems like this, I (shamelessly) recommend to watch this Pluralsight training course:

**[XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1)**

Comment: Hi @Dimitre, does it mean that I have to create a template for each of my element in XSLT to check if it is empty and then replace the string with the default value if it is? And what if im using a dynamic element like <xsl:element name="Fruit{@type}" where type is a number? By the way I am using a number of elements in my XML input and different elemnt names. Thanks

Comment: @zyberjock, You will need a template for each set of element names that have the same default value. As in any other programming language, whatever is specific needs specific code to handle it. As for other requirements that you raise now, you may again, ask a new question. Your current question is completely answered.

Comment: @zyberjock, Of course, one can write a single template that matches any empty element, regardless of its name. However, in this case it would be necessary to have a lot of conditionals (or an `<xsl:choose>`) and this results in more complicated and less-readable code. It is recommended and preferred in the spirit of XSLT, to use many short and simple templates vs. few, big, complicated, unreadable and difficult to maintain ones. In fact, using conditional statements is anti-pattern in any language. As shown here: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/tactical-design-patterns-dot-net-control-flow